# firebase iterate over children nodes ang get their snapshots web

Tags: jquery, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase db with the below structure. How do i iterate over all the children of a particular "cdept".
Say, I there are 10 children under "Signal". How do I start from cdept and get all snapshots of the 10 children?

Firebase ref image:

[image]

Comment: do you want to get batchNo under Signal?

Comment: @PeterHaddad kinda yeah. If there were 'X' unique children under "SIGNAL" with each having "Y" properties. I need to get a snapshot of each of those "X" children.

Comment: try `var ref = firebase.database().ref("cdept");

ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var signal=snapshot.val().Signal;
 });`

Comment: @PeterHaddad thanks a ton, got it :)